# Failed to check license ilog.rules.res.xu.IlrLocalizedResourceException: error code: XU.ERROR.10700

Tags: ilog, jrules

I am trying to execute iLog jRules (Version 7.1)  from Plain Java program. I am using J2SE session factory. Still I am getting below error. Can someone please enlighten ? Also what is the best and simple way to execute jRules rules from java main method ?

```
6/9/14 4:48 PM [SEVERE]    10700 - -.- - Failed to check license ilog.rules.res.xu.IlrLocalizedResourceException: Failed to check license, error code: XU.ERROR.10700
at ilog.rules.res.xu.util.IlrResourceExceptionHelper.createResourceException(IlrResourceExceptionHelper.java:44)
at ilog.rules.res.xu.util.IlrResourceExceptionHelper.createResourceException(IlrResourceExceptionHelper.java:78)
at ilog.rules.res.xu.spi.IlrManagedXUConnectionFactory.verifyRESLicense(IlrManagedXUConnectionFactory.java:1108)
at ilog.rules.res.xu.spi.IlrManagedXUConnectionFactory.getRulesetProvider(IlrManagedXUConnectionFactory.java:883)
at ilog.rules.res.xu.spi.IlrManagedXUConnection.getRulesetProvider(IlrManagedXUConnection.java:280)
at ilog.rules.res.xu.spi.IlrManagedXUConnection.createEngineManager(IlrManagedXUConnection.java:1659)
at ilog.rules.res.xu.spi.IlrManagedXUConnection.getEngineManager(IlrManagedXUConnection.java:1591)
at ilog.rules.res.xu.spi.IlrManagedXUConnection.getRulesetParameters(IlrManagedXUConnection.java:1508)
at ilog.rules.res.xu.cci.IlrXUConnection.getRulesetParameters(IlrXUConnection.java:499)
at ilog.rules.res.xu.cci.IlrXUInteraction.getRulesetInformation(IlrXUInteraction.java:739)
at ilog.rules.res.xu.cci.IlrXUInteraction.dispatchExecution(IlrXUInteraction.java:185)
at ilog.rules.res.xu.cci.IlrXUInteraction.execute(IlrXUInteraction.java:343)
at ilog.rules.res.xu.cci.IlrXUInteraction.execute(IlrXUInteraction.java:459)
at ilog.rules.res.xu.cci.IlrCCIClient.executeInteraction(IlrCCIClient.java:189)
at ilog.rules.res.xu.cci.IlrCCIRuleEngineClient.getRulesetArchiveProperties(IlrCCIRuleEngineClient.java:699)
at ilog.rules.res.session.util.IlrTraceHelper.<init>(IlrTraceHelper.java:111)
at ilog.rules.res.session.impl.IlrStatelessSessionBase.execute(IlrStatelessSessionBase.java:97)
at poc.PojoClientRunnerImpl.executeentpocrules(PojoClientRunnerImpl.java:88)
at poc.Main.main(Main.java:28)
Caused by: ilog.jum.client700.IluSAMAccessDeniedException: At 2014-06-09 11:18:33 GMT,    SAM 3.0.0.1040: Access denied to module 'RES4J'.
If you want to inspect your access key, please do the following: 
java -cp [location]sam.jar ilog.jum.client700.IluSAMAccessKey -summary
```

Comment: Are you running any trail version which is expired?

Comment: Not sure but our deployment team mentioned it is a full version. Can I check it somewhere ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this issue resolved. It was because jar version mismatch. I was using jRules Studio version 7.1.1 and was executing using jRules version 7.0.0 jars .

I modified my classpath to use version 7.1.1 jars for jRules version 7.1.1 rule studio.